# Close opened cmd window from .bat file open application and execute file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a .bat file which opens an application and then executes a file that runs a job within the application. I cannot close the cmd window which opens when the task runs in windows task scheduler.

```
"C:\Proram Files (x86)\ \   \   Robot.exe" execute =f "S:\dept\     Team\   \   YearEndAudit\Main.xaml"
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Jeff

Comment: Please provide specifics about how you're running the .bat file in Task Scheduler (such as the exact command line that is being executed).

Comment: maybe this? `start "" "%programfiles(x86)%\restofpath\Robot.exe" execute =f "S:\dept\ Team\rest of path\YearEndAudit\Main.xaml"`

Comment: Well, perhaps you should review your paths…

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you, but what I understood was:

- You are opening an executable with your CMD but are unable to close
  the CMD after that.

I'm pretty sure that this amount of information is more than enough to solve your case, but we have very little data anyway, and the data is confusing. Please try to improve on your next post.

What is happening is that you are probably just putting the name of the program / script in your CMD, like:

```
program.exe
```

This causes the program to depend on the CMD to run, and also prevents the window from being closed. You can solve this problem using *"start"* at the beginning of everything, such as:

```
start "" "X:\Path\program.exe" execute -f "everythingyouwants"
```

You may need to be in the program folder, since some programs done lazily may consider your current location as the default location and may not find the dependencies they need.
If you care to stay in the folder you are currently in, you can use:

```
pushd "thepath\ofthe\program"
start program.exe
popd
```

Another way is to hide the window creating a script in VBS, such as:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c X:\YOURSCRIPTPATH\YOURSCRIPTNAME.bat/cmd"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

However, if the path also needs quotes, we can have conflicts. The above is not ideal but may help sometime.

If none of this works for you, let us know.

***Hope this helps,

K.***

Comment: the code entire code section `set local=%cd% cd "thepath\ofthe\prog...` is not ideal, it can simply be rewritten as `pushd "thepath\ofthe\prgram\"` then `start "" "program.exe"` then `popd` it is also important to note that `start "" "program.exe ..` is a better way to use `start`, `start` might interpret the first set of double quotes as  a title, so giving an empty title is prefered.

Comment: But I am keeping some of that, as some programs consider their current location as yours, which can interfere when they are executed.

Comment: `pushd` still changes to the location and `popd` returns to the last location. try it yourself, simply copy this and paste in `cmd` and you'll see the result. `cd & pushd %programfiles% & cd & popd & cd` I have however never had any problems with anything interfering, if you quote corectly and specify the correct paths to output/input etc. it will always work.

Comment: I don't use popd or pushd as often, my scripts were more general and needed a variable for the place where it was executed, because the current location (%cd%) could die at any time. Anyway, I think keeping a low level of complexity is important, but I will add that anyway ...

Comment: This can be a problem especially with some old games and scripts as they don't expect you to call them from an unknown place. Scripts even use the execution location (X:\ indows\System32 for example) to search for your files. They may not find it because of that. It was just a warning, he is dealing with an .xaml script himself, it could help.

Comment: You mean `%systemroot%\SYSTEM32`? It is not a problem if you know the OS.

Comment: The example was that you start cmd as an administrator to run the executable and its original path is %systemroot%\system32 instead of, for example,%programfiles%\program\lib ...

Comment: ...its original patch *become* *